# What are these JVM daemon threads created in simple java code?

Tags: java, jvm

I have so simple java app, It simply creates an object, calls a function on it all these inside an infinite loop

```
public class h { 
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            B b = new B();
            b.print();
        }
    }
}

class B { 
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello I'am class B");
    }
}
```

Opening the `jvisualvm` I see 10 threads created by the JVM, only one active which is the main thread and 9 daemons.

What is the usage of these 9 threads ?

And is anyone of them related to Garabage collection in any manner ?
[image]

Note:
output of `java -version`:

```
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

OS :  Arch Linux 4.8.6-1

Comment: The loop is infinite

Comment: @progy_rock  really?

Comment: @progy_rock, My mistake I will fix the description

Comment: @n247s Yep. `while(true){}` is an infinite loop.

Comment: how did you start your java app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`Reference Handler`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8b04ee324a1a/src/share/classes/java/lang/ref/Reference.java#l120) thread is responsible for adding Weak, Soft and Phantom references discovered by Garbage Collector into their registered [ReferenceQueues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html).
- [`Finalizer`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8b04ee324a1a/src/share/classes/java/lang/ref/Finalizer.java#l186) thread runs `finalize` method of the objects ready to be finalized.
- [`Signal Dispatcher`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/812ed44725b8/src/share/vm/runtime/os.cpp#l241) waits for specific OS signals and handles them. In particular, it makes thread dump on `SIGQUIT`, and also initiates VM shutdown process on `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGHUP`.
- [`Attach Listener`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/812ed44725b8/src/share/vm/services/attachListener.cpp#l407) thread supports [Dynamic Attach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/) mechanism. It listens for incoming Dynamic Attach connections and executes VM commands. For example, it is used by `jstack`, `jmap` and `jcmd` utilities.
- `RMI TCP Accept` thread obviously accepts new RMI connections.
- `RMI TCP Connection` threads serve the established RMI connections.
- `RMI Scheduler` runs RMI background tasks like [DGC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/dgc/DGC.html).
- `JMX server connection timeout` thread terminates JMX connetion when needed.

`Reference Handler`, `Finalizer` and partly `RMI Scheduler` are related to GC.

Comment: Thank you, but I believe this answer needs a lot of research to understand every word written here.

Comment: @ShadyAtef indeed, in short you don't need to know. BTW If you do a thread dump you will find more threads such as the GC and compiler threads. These are just the threads running Java code.

Answer (score 1):

The `Reference Handler` is for handling `Reference`s (`SoftReference`, `WeakReference`, `PhantomReference` and their subclasses), the `Finalizer` threads calls the `finalize()` method of finalizable objects.

The `JMX` and `RMI` threads are what allows you to watch the running JVM.

I don't know what the other two threads do.

Comment: How `RMI` is used to monitor the running JVM ?

Comment: RMI is used as a transport mechanism for JMX between VisualVM and your running JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I only recognize the bottom 5 threads as being default for a java application. Although every JVM may use different threads for various tasks. If a Thread is set to deamon it means the JVM will shutdown eventhough that deamon-thread is still running. The 'main' Thread is a non-deamon Thread meaning that as soon as the 'main' Thread is finnished, the JVM will shutdown.

Regarding their tasks, basically their names tell what they do. The 'finallizer' thread is the one responsible for garbage collection (mainly). The 'Attach Listener', 'Signal dispatcher' and the 'ReferenceHandler' are threads doing some other background tasks.